# Paralleling without function is possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

Have a nice day!

I have a two function. First without paralleling:

```
def non_parallel():
for a in range(500):
    for b in range(500):
        for c in range(500):
            try:
                if (1+1/a)*(1+1/b)*(1+1/c)==3:
                    print("a=",a,", b=",b,", c=", c, sep='')
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                pass
print ("Run time: ", datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Second is paralleling:

```
def parallel(a):
for b in range(500):
    for c in range(500):
        try:
            if (1+1/a)*(1+1/b)*(1+1/c)==3:
                print("a=",a,", b=",b,", c=", c, sep='')
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
```

Call paralleling function (i have 2 cores):

```
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(parallel)(a) for a in range(500))
```

But without paralleling my script running  0:02:03.972283
Paralleling function: 02:45.182950

I think,  paralleling  function run longer because more time is spent on function call. It is true? Is it possible to parallelize other ways?

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from datetime import datetime
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print (num_cores)

startTime = datetime.now()
def non_parallel():
    for a in range(500):
        for b in range(500):
            for c in range(500):
                try:
                    if (1+1/a)*(1+1/b)*(1+1/c)==3:
                        print("a=",a,", b=",b,", c=", c, sep='')
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                    pass
    print ("Time: ", datetime.now() - startTime)

startTime = datetime.now()
def parallel(a):
    for b in range(500):
        for c in range(500):
            try:
                if (1+1/a)*(1+1/b)*(1+1/c)==3:
                    print("a=",a,", b=",b,", c=", c, sep='')
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                pass
non_parallel()
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(parallel)(a) for a in range(500))  
print ("Time: ", datetime.now() - startTime)
print ("End")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create two jobs (background processes), and then the library feeds them work to do 500 times.  That is going to invoke quite a lot of work.

Try:

```
def parallel(astart):
    for a in range (astart, astart+10):
        for b in range(500):
            for c in range(500):
                try:
                    if (1+1/a)*(1+1/b)*(1+1/c)==3:
                        print("a=",a ,", b=",b,", c=", c, sep='')
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                    pass
```

and

```
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(parallel)(a) for a in range(0,500,10))
```

That will reduce the interprocess communication by a factor of 10, and should make the parallel code faster than the non-parallel.

Answer (score -1):

You are measuring the time wrong. Because you are measuring the time outside the function; the time measured by you after parallel call is the total run time of almost entire program. Your start_time is independent of function calls.

In your function you have measured startTime before the start of each function. But that doesn't matter. When you call the function without parallel it won't take the start time defined above it.

The program would calculate startTime twice. The latest would be taken by the function without paralleling and you get the time from startTime to end of the function call. For paralleling function however the startTime is still the same and you get runtime of non-parallel + parallel

Modify your program this way

```
non_parallel()
startTime = datetime.now() 
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(parallel)(a) for a in range(500)) 
print ("Time: ", datetime.now() - startTime)
print ("End")
```

It will show you the right picture